# ArrayList (issue with removing)

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a Hangman Game. Suppose the word to guess were "lightbulb." When a user guesses a letter that appears more than once in the word, which in this case is "l," I want to remove that letter from the ArrayList in all locations so that the ArrayList contains "ightbub." Below is my code for the class that handles userGuesses and checks for letters in the selected word. FOR THE CODE BELOW: wordToGuess = ("lightbulb")

One other issue: Below this code, I've included the output. As you can see, when I enter the same letter repeatedly, it says I have guessed a letter even though that letter should be removed from the ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InputChecker extends PromptUser{

static int numOfGuesses;
static String userGuess;
static String[] charList;
static boolean contains;

ArrayList<String> characters = new ArrayList<String>();

public boolean alive = true;

static WordSelector ws = new WordSelector();
static LengthReturner lr = new LengthReturner();
static PromptUser pu = new PromptUser();

static String wordToGuess = ws.setWord();
static int wordLength;

public static void finish() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Congratulations! You have finished the game.");
    System.out.println("Coming soon: GUI");
}

public boolean askUser() {
    while(alive == true) {
        boolean validGuess = false;
        while(validGuess == false) {
            userGuess = pu.getUserInput("Enter your guess here:");
            if(userGuess == null || userGuess.length() > 1) {
                validGuess = false;
                System.out.println("Enter ONE letter!");
            } else {
                validGuess = true;
            }
        }   
        wordLength = lr.setLength(wordToGuess);
        charList = wordToGuess.split("(?!^)");
        contains = false;
        for(String c : charList) {
            characters.add(c);
        }
        for (String c : characters) {
            if(userGuess == c) {
                characters.remove(c);
                contains = true;
            }
        }
        if(contains == true) {
            System.out.println("You guessed a letter!");
            numOfGuesses++;
            if(characters.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Congratulations! You have successfully guessed the word, which was " + wordToGuess + ".");
                System.out.println("You took " + numOfGuesses + " guesses!");
                alive = false;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your guess, '" + userGuess + "', is not in the word!");
            numOfGuesses++;
        }
    }
    return alive;
}
}
```

Here is the output when I enter the same letter repeatedly. Notice how it always says that I successfully guessed a letter even though that letter should be removed from the ArrayList. Somehow, remove() is not working right for me. Again, the wordToGuess = ("lightbulb:)

```
Enter your guess here: 
l
You guessed a letter!
Enter your guess here: 
l
You guessed a letter!
Enter your guess here: 
l
You guessed a letter!
Enter your guess here: 
l
You guessed a letter!
Enter your guess here: 
l
You guessed a letter!
Enter your guess here: 
l
You guessed a letter!
Enter your guess here: 
l
You guessed a letter!
Enter your guess here: 
l
You guessed a letter!
Enter your guess here: 
l
You guessed a letter!
```

Comment: You'd figure out your problem quite quickly if you made any attempt at debugging. In particular: you should try printing out `characters` immediately after printing out `"You guessed a letter!"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the lines:

```
    charList = wordToGuess.split("(?!^)");
    contains = false;
    for(String c : charList) {
        characters.add(c);
    }
```

outside the while loop. Since it is in the while loop, it is re-initializing the "characters" in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc for [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) says (in part),

> This method can be called only once per call to [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--). *The **behavior of an iterator is unspecified** if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress **in any way other than by calling this method**.*

Also, you compare `Object` types (including `String`) equality with `equals()` (not `==`). You need something like

```
Iterator<String> iter = characters.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String c = iter.next();
    if (userGuess.equals(c)) {
        // characters.remove(c);
        iter.remove();
        contains = true;
    }
}
```